# Helm deploy Image from a Private Registry (Github) fails

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy an Image which I have pushed to my Github repo packages.
For that I followed [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

When I create the secret, in **--docker-server=< your-registry-server >**  I put **ghcr.io**

This is my cat ~/.docker/config.json

```
{
   "auths": {
      "ghcr.io": {},
      "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
   },
   "credsStore": "desktop",
   "experimental": "disabled",
   "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

And this is Values.yaml

```
image:
  repository: ghcr.io/myrepo/nginx-lua
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: "1.0.0"

imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
```

After deploying I get an error when I see my pods:

```
Failed to pull image "ghcr.io/myrepo/nginx-lua:1.0.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Head https://ghcr.io/v2/myrepo/nginx-lua/manifests/1.0.0: denied: denied
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is your Kubernetes and Helm version? Did you try to use this on one pod like in [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret) ?  You have created own chart or you've used ready one?

Comment: Did you use a personal access token (PAT) for --docker-password in the secret? GitHub user credentials aren't supported for ghcr currently.

Comment: @jrz : were you able to solve this issue. I get the same error when trying from private gcr repo